Using https for internal FQDN for k8s
Is there anyway for k8s pods to communicate internally using FQDN with https?
This is for AWS EKS fargate
e.g.
Service A calls Service B via https://service-b.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local?
i.e curl https://service-b.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
I've tried with this above commands but what I am getting is timeout, but it is perfectly fine when I do it with curl service-b.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local within the pod (service A).
I am unsure if the internal FQDN provides the service of having a https for the pods.
